# PHP search form, trying to display results in different part of page

Tags: php, html, sql

In my index.php I'm including all of the parts of the page.  My structure is basically:

```
    <div id="page">
        <?php include('/home/content/16/7554016/html/template/head.inc.php'); ?>
        <?php include('/home/content/16/7554016/html/template/nav_below.inc.php'); ?>
        <div id="left"><?php include('/home/content/16/7554016/html/template/left.inc.php'); ?></div>
        <div id="body"><?php include('/home/content/16/7554016/html/template/body.inc.php'); ?></div>
        <div id="right"><?php include('/home/content/16/7554016/html/template/right.inc.php'); ?></div>
    </div>

<div id="footer"><?php include('/home/content/16/7554016/html/template/footer.inc.php'); ?></div>
```

I have a self submitting search form in the header.  But, want to display the results in the body.  So, I put the `results.inc.php` in the `body.inc.php`.  But, that obviously won't create a connection with the form in the `head.inc.php`.  How can I do this using all of the includes?  Thank you.

Comment: Explain what is a `self submitting search form`. Does it mean that head.inc.php handles the $_POST submited by your search form?

Comment: results.inc.php handles the $_POST.  results.inc.php is included in the body.inc.php where I want the results.  The form is in the head.inc.php.  By self submitting I mean display results on the same page / $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

Comment: you might want to post some of the code (especially head.inc.php and body.inc.php)...

Answer (score 0):

What connection are you trying to create? If you display the results in the body using php, it doesn't have to be linked to the form, or within the form tags. the php code will be executed in the order it is included.

Comment: It should work then, but doesn't.  It's merely a basic form, then a SELECT/LIKE query to get results.  I have the form in the head and the actual php to get the results is in the body below the head.  The form and results php are on different files.  The head.inc.php has the form and body.inc.php has a <? php include(results.inc.php); which has the results.